# Architecture of "doodle jump" type gameplay infinite looping background

Tags: unity, 2d

I am planning make a doodle jump type game, character jumping on platforms. A scrolling or doodle jump like background which ll appear to move when character moves upward and appear moving (just like in doodle jump) so, my thoughts are for this kind of background is

- to take a large image i.e of 2048x2048, make 2 planes, set this texture to them, when first image ends other ll move its position on top of first, when second ends first ll move on top of second and so on.
- Other approch could be a "Instantiate" and "Destroy" of small images having textures on them according to jumping character position ( which i doubt ll b expensive )

They are my thoughts, I want to go for best approach and would like to listen the best one. Is there any more appropriae way to achieve moveable background, I ll appreciate your suggestions. Thanks.

Comment: Probably related? http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/scrolling-background-loop?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We are in the making of a similiar game, without the left-right scrolling. We decided to load as much texture as we can, becouse it can be real slow when our character moves up fast regardless how we try to load it(eg. AssetBundle's loadAsync). Plus, when our level loads we pre-create(Instantiate) some platforms and particles, but instead of destroy(when they gone out of vision) we will store them and reuse them(classic object pools). So my suggestion is: preload/pre-create then reuse as many `thing` as you can to achive fast gameplay.

Comment: +1 for creating pool and thnx for your suggestion, I have posted my detailed question here, http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/375654/architecture-of-doodle-jump-type-gameplay.html I ll appreciate your suggestions on other points. Thanks